# urlopen/requests.get not getting all page content

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

Using Python, I am trying to scrape a real estate website for information about the flats. All the information that I need is in a javascript variable stored in the head of the page (ava_data).

I'm working from cloud9 (online IDE) and I would prefer not switching out of it.
I'm using Beautiful Soup for scraping.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import requests

url = 'http://www.seloger.com/list.htm?idtt=1&idtypebien=1,2&ci=750120,750114&tri=initial&naturebien=1&nb_pieces=2&pxmax=1250&surfacemin=40'
seloger_html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(seloger_html.text,'html.parser')
path = os.getcwd() + '/COMPLET/scrap_seloger.txt'
f = open(path, 'w')
f.write(soup.prettify().encode('utf8'))
```

I can't *consistently* get all the information from the page in my soup. To verify this, I have written the prettified soup in a txt file.
When it works, I get the following file (same as what I get from Inspection in Chrome) : https://ufile.io/eue0b
When it doesn't, I get the following : https://ufile.io/f1dnx

I have managed to get the right file only 4-5 times out of several dozens trials. From what I can tell, it was right the first time I tried with urllib.urlopen() and the first time I tried with requests.get() . As far as I know, I haven't done anything special before it worked the other times. And every time it worked, it failed the next time.

- I tried disabling Javascript on Chrome before opening the url to get the DOM without JS. It was the same as before. --> I'm guessing it's not a problem of stuff added to the DOM with JS.
- As hinted before, I tried urllib and requests. Both work inconsistently.
- Cookies shouldn't be an issue as the session changes every time.
- As I am on Cloud9, I can't use Selenium with a browser.

Comment: Put a [mcve] *in the question*. See [ask].

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen that. I have added it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That site is using some anti-scraping techniques. You have to set `User-Agent` headers to fake browser visit.

```
url = 'http://www.seloger.com/list.htm?idtt=1&idtypebien=1,2&ci=750120,750114&tri=initial&naturebien=1&nb_pieces=2&pxmax=1250&surfacemin=40'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0'}
seloger_html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Also try not to scrape too fast.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I'm happy to know it wasn't some stupid thing I missed. Could you perhaps tell me what made you know that they use anti-scraping techniques ?